# stuck in while loop python

Tags: python, while-loop

I am creating a chat server in python and got quite far as a noob in the language. I am having 1 problem at the moment which I want to solve before I go further, but I cannot seem to find how to get the problem solved.

It is about a while loop that continues..

in the below code is where it goes wrong

```
while 1:
    try:
        data = self.channel.recv ( 1024 )
        print "Message from client: ", data
        if "exit" in data:
            self.channel.send("You have closed youre connection.\n")
            break
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break
    except:
        raise
```

When this piece of code get executed, on my client I need to enter "exit" to quit the connection. This works as a charm, but when I use CTRL+C to exit the connection, my server prints "Message from client: " a couple of thousand times.

where am I going wrong?

Comment: When you use CTRL+C, is that on the client or server side?

Comment: It sounds like you're closing the client. Recv probably returns false and thus you're stuck in the while loop.

Comment: I am using CTRL+C on the client side.

Comment: Think twice about using `if 'exit' in data:`.  If this is a chat server, this means no one can ever send a message containing the word 'exit' unless they manage to make it span across 2 buffer-sized data blocks.  `if data == 'exit':` will probably work more as you'd like.

Comment: @sr2222 I agree. However in the context of my chatserver, it does not seem to work if I replace the if statement with "if data == "exit" ", therefor I replaced the word with "/exit". This works fine now. Thx for the advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're pressing Ctrl-C on the client side. This causes the server's `self.channel` to get closed.

Since calling `recv()` on a closed channel immediately returns a blank string, your server code gets stuck in an infinite loop.

To fix this, add the following line to your server code:

```
data = self.channel.recv ( 1024 )
if not data: break # <<< ADD THIS
```

Or, as suggested by @sr2222, you can combine both this and your current check into one:

```
if not data or 'exit' in data:
```

This will exit the loop if the channel has been closed.

Comment: Or just `if not data or 'exit' in data:`

Comment: Wow damm I indeed missed this... couldnt wrap my head around it, both the answer of NPE and sr2222 are correct.  THX

Comment: Oh, sorry NPE, you are right, it's probably better to have 2 separate checks, since the `'exit' in data` check sends data back over the connection, which will not be valid if data is empty.

Comment: @sr2222: Yes and no. AFAIK, calling `send()` on a closed channel is a no-op. However, some might question this approach on stylistic grounds.